# Mutate Error when attempting to sum a column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains a column of numbers. I am trying to add those numbers together through the mutate function so that I can create a new variable containing the total sum of those numbers, and then add that new variable onto the end of my existing data frame.

I am trying to use the following line of code:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(total_sum = sum(orders$numbers))
```

But when I run that line of code I get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it? My data frame is called orders but the column I want to add is called numbers.

Comment: Try `mutate(orders, total_sum = sum(numbers))`.

Comment: If this is not working, please use `dput` to share your `orders` data frame.

Comment: That worked! Any way I can get it to only add the total to my data frame once instead of for every single row in my data frame?

Comment: Try `summarise`